# Need help to understand the SUM(CASE part of a query

Tags: sql

I need a little help to understand understanding a `SUM(CASE` issue, mainly this section: `THEN c.quantity * dbo.Get_Qty_Sum(c.Schedule_ref, c.Schedule_Line, c.master_part) END)`.

Here's the query :

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN c.component LIKE '52-%' THEN c.quantity * dbo.Get_Qty_Sum(c.Schedule_ref, c.Schedule_Line, c.master_part) END) AS Ref_Qty
```

Comment: It is unclear as to whether you don't understand the `SUM`, `CASE`, or your user-defined function `dbo.Get_Qty_Sum`.

Comment: I'm dont understand the structure

Comment: This is a view script, (dbo.Get_Qty_Sum) is a scalar function. I need to understand how the code is combining the scalar function with (c.Schedule_ref, c.Schedule_Line, c.master_part) END)

Comment: My answer is based on MS SQL Server.  Adding a tag to indicate which RDBMS is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The scalar function, `dbo.Get_Qty_Sum` expects 3 parameters to be passed (`c.Schedule_ref`, `c.Schedule_Line`, `c.master_part`). The 3 values are taken in and then a single value is returned as shown in the example below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Qty_Sum]( @schedule_ref int, @schedule_line int, @master_part )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @schedule_ref + @schedule_line + @master_part 
END
```